# Are there any CMS based on document-based database?

Tags: content-management-system, document-based-database

I did some googling, not much come up.

Comment: I've thought this would be a great utilization of document db's.  And a great opportunity to start an open source project.

Comment: Kirby looks really promising and totally document driven. http://getkirby.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Drupal 7](http://sf2010.drupal.org/conference/sessions/mongodb-humongous-drupal) has support for MongoDB coming ([alpha release](http://drupal.org/project/mongodb)).

Answer (score 0):

I found [Avinu](http://www.avinu.org/) linked from Mongo's [production deployment](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Deployments) page.  I didn't see any other CMSs there, though.  Edit:  And they don't actually have any source available right now.

Answer (score 0):

[LocomotiveCMS](http://locomotivecms.com) is an open source CMS written in Ruby which uses MongoDB as its data store.